# Set homescreen / wallpaper image programmatically on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, image

I recently saw this video: https://twitter.com/appbackground/status/806965964675878912

It seems like they're able to set the home screen image programmatically. Is this now possible on iOS?

Comment: This is not part of any public API's.  That video is either edited and fake, or they are using private APIs to do this.  And if the latter, Apple will not approve it for use on the App Store.  So the answer is "yes, there are ways" but nothing that will be distributable on the App Store.

Comment: But it looks it is already on the app store https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/background-best-photos-from/id1171036231 have you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Background dev here:)
Of course video has a cut (zoom on screen when saving photo).

Comment: Thanks for clarification Adam.

Comment: Nicely done. It's a shame iOS doesn't allow this, right?!